Is Bjarne implying that using-directives make it impossible to qualify names in that namespace later?
Am I misunderstanding, Bjarne's 2nd edition Chapter 3 of A Tour of C++ section on namespaces as it seems to imply that once a using-directive is used, we can't qualify it?

By using a using-directive, we lose the ability to selectively use
names from that namespace, so this facility should be used carefully,
usually for a library that’s pervasive in an application (e.g., std)
or during a transition for an application that didn’t use namespaces.

If this isn't it, what does this citation mean? I didn't see it posted in the 2nd errata. I tested this out with this code and it compiled and ran without any issue.
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    std::cout << "works\n";
}


You still have problems with the non-qualified names. We have seen people discovering new namespaces, so adding both using namespace std; and using namespace std::ranges;, and then nothing works because most names collide.

What this passage really means is that you are losing the ability to selectively not use names from that namespace. They will now be found by unqualified lookup whether you want them or not, thereby defeating the point of the namespaces, which is to help avoid name collisions.

Watch this : C++ Weekly - Ep 305 - Stop Using using namespace. This will explain quite a bit about why using namespace has its problems. Another example : A common problem on windows is that min/max are already macros (from windows.h) and these will conflict with std::min / std::max functions when using using namespace std;

Bjarne's point is exactly the opposite of your interpretation. The problem is not that it is impossible to fully qualify names - because that is NEVER impossible. The problem is that resolving the use of unqualified names becomes ambiguous (so won't compile) if two or more namespaces (including the unnamed namespace) declare the same name.  If you don't remove ALL using namespace directives that cause ambiguity entirely from your code, the ONLY way to resolve that ambiguity is to use fully qualified names.  That totally defeats the usual goal (e.g. reduced typing) of using namespace.

@BoP, Is this what you mean by std::ranges? https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/ranges

Yes, that's it. And if you then add two using namespace, the compiler will find two of everything. The best is to have none, and specify std::cout, just like in the example in this question.

It is not about using qualified names, but unqualified ones.
For example, if you use using namespace std; with the intention to only use cout unqualified, then you still did import all other names from std as well and they will all be considered for uses of unqualified names. You can't selectively import only some names from std with the statement and you need to be aware of that.
For example:
#include<iostream>

using namespace std;

void move(long i)
{
    cout << "move(" << i << ")\n";
}

int main()
{
    move(42);
}

Since C++11 this program may or may not print move(42), because there is a std::move function in the standard library that would be a better overload resolution match for move(42) if its declaration is reachable from the call. And because of using namespace std; this std::move library name is also made available to unqualified lookup, even if this is not your intention.
Whether the declaration is reachable or not is unspecified because <iostream> is not guaranteed to declare it, but also isn't required not to declare it.
